# WordPress get posts by category_name

Tags: wordpress

I have a CPT in the single-portfolio.php file where I would like to list blog posts according to their category.

That is, the items I have in my CPT called Portfolio are "India", "USA", "Mexico", "Spain" and "Italy". The blog categories are exactly the same.

How can I get the news in the India page to return to me with the India category? And on the USA page the news with category USA...etc

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'category_name' => 'usa'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<section class="news-slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="slider-container">
          <div class="slick-slider">
            <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>
            <div class="slick-slide" style="background-image:url(<?= the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)">
              <a class="permalink" href="<?= the_permalink() ?>"></a>
              <div class="title-container">
                <span class="meta-category"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span>
                <h3 class="title"><?php the_title() ?></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So, to understand your issue: You have a Custom Post Type (CPT) called "Portfolio". When you say "items" (e.g. India, USA, etc), what are you talking about? A taxonomy term, a post name? I'm assuming you want this to be dynamic.

Comment: That's right, works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are trying to show regular `Posts` on your CPT post where the name of the CPT Post is the same as the posts category name.

If that's the case you can do this (new lines are commented):

```
<?php

// Get the post object;
global $post;
// Get the post_name (e.g. slug) of the post
$slug = $post->post_name;
// As long as the slug of your CPT post is the same as the slug of your post category, this works.

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  // Use the $slug variable here.
  'category_name' => $slug,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<section class="news-slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="slider-container">
          <div class="slick-slider">
            <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>
            <div class="slick-slide" style="background-image:url(<?= the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)">
              <a class="permalink" href="<?= the_permalink() ?>"></a>
              <div class="title-container">
                <span class="meta-category"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span>
                <h3 class="title"><?php the_title() ?></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```